# Office-js Deployment

Tags: office-js

I am working on a Word Add-in using JavaScript and would like to deploy it locally for some users. When I say locally I mean without connecting to any server. I understand I can do it using shared folder which reside on same machine but I have some server side code for some calculations or document formatting based on xslt. I was thinking of using something like IISExpress and host asp.net app on it for server side processing. Any other ideas or issues you have encounter in similar case.

Thanks in advance.
Manoj

Answer (score 1):

For local/in-house solutions that cannot access external networks, you can use the Office-JS [NPM package](http://github.com/officedev/office-js), which is basically just a copy of what's on the CDN. It's not a pure package per say as it still uses the loader to determine which file to use. So, don't expect the typical NPM package behavior - but it works. 
This is also not frequently updated as the CDN version - but in the future this should become in-sync with the CDN version. 
Note that the usage of Office-js APIs will still generate telemetry calls to Office servers. So, in your logs/console you may see some failed API calls because of network restrictions - but it should have no impact on your application logic.

For distribution - you will have to use the file-share option or use SharePoint catalog. More information is available on that on learn.microsoft.com/office

Comment: Thanks Sudhi for details.

Comment: Have you tried running the package on something like IISExpress so that server type processing can be done. One of the task the current VBA does is pick few documents and merge them to one following certain logic etc.